# Has the government done enough to re-integrate formerly demonically possessed people back into society?

Tags: society, culture, religion

This setting takes place in a world similar to our own technologically. The country operates as a theocratic democracy, where priests run the government from behind the scenes. They elect leaders from a pool of applicants, and then allow those chosen to run for office. This guarantees some democratic privileges while ensuring that the official state church stays in control. This reality exists side by side with an alternate dimension called chaos, where near powerful demonic gods exist. These gods are not sentient in the way humans are, but exist as pure thought and emotion. They represent the seven deadly sins, and are powered by our emotional extremes. The seven gods have countless demons under them that are created from their energies.

An invisible barrier exists between the two dimensions that prevents these demons from manifesting in our world. 99% of the time, the barrier does its job of keeping the demons out. However, it can drop at random intervals, or weaken for a limited amount of time. These occurrences cannot be predicted with any accuracy. During these times, an opportunistic demon can push through the barrier and possess a person. Demonic possession works in the way of a demon forcefully penetrating the shell of the human body and taking over the soul. The demon is now in complete control, wearing the individual like a glove. While it is in control of the host, it would seek to cause chaos and destruction wherever it goes, intent on spreading the sin it was made from in anyway possible. The only way to free a victim from their prison, outside of killing them, is by an exorcism performed by a priest. This banishes the demon back to its realm and hopefully leaves the host alive.

Possession is extremely rare, as the barrier is mostly stable and the few spirits that get through usually dissipate due to not being able to survive in this realm for long without a body. Faith and belief in the religion also double as a spiritual shield that surrounds a person, providing a measure of protection. The popular saying "my faith is my shield" stems from this. As a result, the church is present in all walks of life and have instilled in the populace a deeply religious fervor. The government needs a way of dealing with the individuals who survived their exorcism. They are hesitant to kill them because it is understood that they were not in control of their actions while possessed. However, there is disagreement on how to approach the situation. A few parameters:

1. Demonic possession is a traumatic and painful process, akin to a spiritual rape of the individual. Survivors experience symptoms related to PTSD, including depression, anxiety, nightmares, etc. Many people never fully recover, and are forced to deal with a range of issues for the rest of their lives.
2. These individuals are referred to as "tainted" by the populace. Although it is understood that they are victims, they are also viewed with a measure of suspicion and hostility. It is thought that they have been corrupted by the evil spirit, and more susceptible to chaotic thoughts. The tainted are forced to live in a world that doesn't trust them, and are often ostracized by former friends and family.
3. While all influence of the demon has disappeared after the exorcism, its removal leaves behind an open wound on the soul of the person, invisible to the human eye. This wound never completely heals, and may potentially leave the soul open to possession by another opportunistic entity. Although this belief is unofficial and has never been proven statistically, it has been adopted by many influential members of the clergy.

After some time in an isolated facility, The government has tried to integrate people back into society. They are implanted with a tracking device that broadcasts their position to authorities. In addition, they are forbidden from going to certain areas, taking certain jobs, and must register in a database for tainted individuals. They must check in with a clergy member every so often,who comes to their home and judges their mental and physical state. These people will go through this process for the rest of their lives.

Based on these conditions, has the government done enough to secure the safety of the public as well as the victims?

Comment: this looks like a broad opinion based question about a story set in a world

Comment: How can I narrow it down?

Comment: This may be a job better left to private enterprise, not government. Even government contractors, perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like a story. You could write a good novel exploring this topic. I think I'd like to read it. But we can't really write it for you.

Comment: I thought I've just read this question last week. Let me ask again, how often and how many possessed cases happen? If it is common enough, building a secluded settlement may be a solution.

Comment: @AdiNugroho You read it yesterday in the [Meta Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4782/28789)

Comment: There are a few hundred people that end up being possessed each century.

Answer (score 6):

It's an interesting topic, but it seems painfully close to the way far too many people view mental illness, even today.

About the only way these people could be really re-integrated, would be to put them into a different community.  the stigma attached to possesion (and mental illness in the real world) would make it extremely hard in a place where people already know your past.  There is going to be an inherent level of distrust.

Since there are no direct physical side effects, you could move the victim to another city and place them on a spiritual probation.  An assigned caseworker priest in the guise of a father confessor.  That keeps the identity secret and allows the person to appear to everyone else as a deeply religious member of society.

The priestly probation officer and the "punishment" of leaving his original home might appeal to the clergy who think that the stain makes them liable to be co-opted by downbelow a second time.

You can also get bonus plot points when someone finds out who your formerly possesed was.